# Executing the "+p command

Tags: 16.10, gvim

I'm trying to type `"+` for executing the command `"+p`, but it doesn't work so far. Could anyone be able to tell me what I have to do to fix it?

When I type `:reg`, I got the following picture :

[image]

In fact, I'd like to paste the content of `"+`. However, when I wrote `"+p`, it is supposed to paste its content, but `"` and `+` doesn't display on the screen.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question should be more comprehensive _+p_ doesn't actually say what your trying to achieve .

Comment: Sorry, for that!! I'll modify my question such as to be more comprehensive.

Comment: Does `"+p` not result in it pasting "The Dursleys had everything they wanted..."?

Answer (score 2):

When you do a command and make the destination a register, you wont see any sort of visual indication that it did anything.  You could install something like `screenkey` to confirm that you are actually typing the keys you think you are.  Half the time, I stupidly press ' instead of " when trying to target registers... I just don't use them frequently enough.

Since the `"+` register is the X clipboard, you could confirm that it copied by running a clipboard application.  For example, xclipboard (provided by the `x11-apps` package, `sudo apt-get install x11-apps`).

Try an experiment.  In a terminal, launch xclipboard, and send it to the background.  So: `xclipboard &`

Then in vim, type a sentence, and then hit escape to make sure you're no longer in insert mode, then type `"+yy` and see if the sentence pops up in the clipboard.

Then you can try `"+p` and confirm that it pastes it.  Or at least you should be able to see what was in the clipboard that should have been copied/pasted.

Sure, the `:reg` command will show you the x clipboard content, too, but having a separate clipboard app will let you see it as you're hitting keys.

Edit:
Apparently you can skip the screenkey usage and just do `:set showcmd` as @muru points out.

Comment: In Vim, you can do `:set showcmd` and then partial commands like `"+` will show up in the status bar.

Comment: If I could up vote your comment more than once, I would.  Thanks!